# Code clarification : DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("intro.csv"));

Tags: java, oop

I'm confused by this java code, most likely due to my lack of object oriented programming skills.

```
DataModel model = new FileDataModel (new File("intro.csv"));
```

How is DataModel related to FileDataModel. Is this a 'isa' relationship? where FileDataModel isa DataModel, and if so, in general the parent class can equate to any subclass? Also can a object equate to another class where there is no relationship at all in terms of parent/subclass?

Comment: did you understand my explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question, yes.

`FileDataModel` is a `DataModel` and so one can give a `DataModel` reference a `FileDataModel` object... this is called upcasting, and is a core principle of OOP.

As for your second question, no. upcasting only works when the reference is a parent of the object created.

```
Number n = new Integer(1);// Integer is of type Number
String s = new Integer(5);// Integer is unrelated to String
```

In the example, I create an integer `n` but the reference is of type `Number`. That works because `Integer` extends (is a child of) `Number`. However, the second line won't compile. This is because `String` and `Integer` are not related to one another (neither is a parent of the other).

Answer (score 1):

Will have to guess based on abscence of additional information but:

`FileDataModel` looks to extend or implement `DataModel` (I'd guess that it extends it) thus the `DataModel` model, is, in reality, a `FileDataModel`, but because all `FileDataModel`s are `DataModel` (this is a fundamental priciple of OOP and extending / inheritance) it's possible to assign it to a `DataModel` object reference.

If `FileDataModel` didn't extend `DataModel` the compiler would error telling you this, unless you explicitly cast the FileDataModel to a DataModel, in which case you may end up with a runtime error, assuming the FileDataModel couldn't be cast to a DataModel.

So for instance if I attempt to assign:

```
String s = new Integer(5);
```

I will get a compile time warning that Integer is not a String, and so can't be assigned to it.

If I however do this:

```
String s = (String)new Integer(5);
```

I will not get a compiler error, I will hoever get an [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html)